# Can not clear an array component variable inside Observable subscribe method

Tags: angular, observable

Here is my code:

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
   dataB: any[] = [];
   ngOnInit() {
     this._myService.DataSource$.subscribe(dataA => {
       this.dataB = [];
       console.log('length of dataB (before): ' + this.dataB.length);
       dataA.forEach(da => {
         var newData = {
           id: 0,
           name: da.name,
           verifyMethod: '',
           notes: ''
         };
         this.dataB.push(newData);
       }
       console.log('length of dataB (after): ' + this.dataB.length);
     });
   }
}
```

`_myService.DataSources$` is subscribed to elsewhere in the application, so in this component, it always run twice through the `subscribe` method, the peculiar thing is that `this.dataB` keeps growing even though I reset it to empty array at the very top of the `subscribe` method (NOTE: there are only 8 dataA items each time), the two `console.log` print out is like below:

```
length of dataB (before): 0
length of dataB (after): 8
length of dataB (before): 0
length of dataB (after): 16
```

My goal is to just to recreate the array of `dataB` every time new `dataA` is available, but it looks like it keeps generating duplicates along with the multiple concurrent `_myService.DataSource$` subscription calls in the app! How can I reliably reset `this.dataB` each time in the subscribe method?

Comment: I think your dataA's length is 16 for second time, please double check this. You could also use array's map function instead forEach + push methods to make your code clearer.

Comment: @udalmik no, it is 8, I step through the code each time, the incoming dataA is always 8 items, actually, I also look at the 16-item array, it contains exactly two copies of the same set of items

Comment: @ForComment please add this at first on function : `console.log('length of dataA (before): ' + this.dataA.length);`. cause i also think that your `dataA` is increasing.

Comment: Ok, I simplified the dataA in the code snippet above, it is actually being processed in another process, and in there, it is not being reset to empty, indeed. I've spent 3 hours staring at this, I felt so stupid. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1):

You need to unsubscribe your observable to prevent loading more data and memory leak.

And the simplest way is to use ngrx [take](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/take) operator, your final code would look like something.

```
ngOnInit() {
 this._myService.DataSource$
 .pipe(take(1)) // <==== note this part it will take only one value and unsubscribe then
 .subscribe(dataA => {
   this.dataB = [];
   console.log('length of dataB (before): ' + this.dataB.length);
   dataA.forEach(da => {
     var newData = {
       id: 0,
       name: da.name,
       verifyMethod: '',
       notes: ''
     };
     this.dataB.push(newData);
   }
   console.log('length of dataB (after): ' + this.dataB.length);
 });
}
```

Hope this solve your issue.

Comment: Kamran, this is a good suggestion, I am always a bit unclear, so if use `take(1).subscribe`, is it just one time getting data or is it still continuous? I mean when new data become available, it will be triggered to get it again, right?

Comment: Nope, it will not. take(1) ensures that the subscriber will receive only one data and then unsubscribe. No more values will be received even if the source emits new values.

Comment: @ForComment it will take only one value and then unsubscribe you can read more details in the link on `take` in my answer.